# what is the difference between == and ===?

Tags: php

I'm learning about cakephp, and I see much conditionals like:

```
if( x === y){
}
```

I've looked for it, but I don't find anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` compares the values of two variables. If they are of different types, they are converted to a common type and then compared.

`===`, on the other hand, is more strict. It requires the two sides to be of the same type as well.

```
php> = 5 == "5"
true
php> = 5 === "5"
false
```

Answer (score 2):

`==` wil do auto type conversion, `===` won't

This means that:

`0 == "0"` evaluates to `TRUE`, because internally when comparing strings and numbers, a string is converted to a number when using `==`.

`0 === "0"` evaluates to `FALSE`, there is no type conversion done and a integer `0` is not equal to a string.

More info in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [more documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: Also 0 == "something" evaluates to true. That it the reason why its bad coding to not use strict comparison when working with strings or where it could be used. See the [last chapter](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/01/22/cakephp-tips/) here for details. The rule should be "as strict as possible".